# Mixing build.sbt with project *.scala files: should all be unified in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Using SBT 0.13.13, our build definition is inherited from an older project. Currently there are a build.sbt and some project/*.scala files. These scala files follow the same pattern. Here is an example:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object Docs {
  lazy val docTask = TaskKey[Unit]("docPackage", "Generate Scaladoc")

  lazy val settings = Seq(
    docTask := {
      val docs = (doc in Compile).value
      IO.copyDirectory(docs, new java.io.File("src/main/resources/myapp-scaladoc"), overwrite = true)
    },

    docTask := (docTask.dependsOn(doc in Compile)).value
  )
}
```

[Appendix: .scala build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Full-Def.html) says

> In the previous versions of sbt, .scala was the only way to create
>   multi-project build definition

**Question**: I suppose this mean the use of separate project/*.scala files is discouraged. If so, is it OK to move the code of these *.scala file and put them all in build.sbt?

Answer (score 0):

There is little functional difference between having code in `project/` and code in `build.sbt`.

The advantage to putting code in a `.scala` file in `project/` is that all symbols in it are imported into the namespace of all `build.sbt` files in all subprojects of your build. This means that helper methods, constants, plugins, or other Scala code can live in a single location, but be called from anywhere.

Ultimately, whether to use this features comes down to whether you want shared items configured in a single location, or in multiple locations.

If you prefer to have your project settings configured entirely in separate `build.sbt` files in their subproject directories, putting shared settings in the `project/` folder is the way to do that.

If you're OK with having shared settings configured in the root `build.sbt` file (or if you don't use any subproject `build.sbt` files), you can consolidate all of your shared configuration into it.